# Browser and web app multicast DNS

Tags: dns, mdns

I have a web server with a web application running in local network without a DNS server.  I would like to use this address to open my application: http://myapplication/

Now I must set the webserver ip in local ns hosts file (es. in windows c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\hosts) of each client computer like this:
192.168.0.22   myapplication

Can I use multicast DNS to distribute the service ip in the network? If yes, how to format the service name?
Modern browser use multicast if the DNS record doesn't exists?

Comment: Don't know why your Google search did not give you this --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS

Comment: Did you find in this wiki page an answer of these questions? "How to format the service name? Modern browser use multicast if the DNS record doesn't exists?"

Comment: Yes.  That page explains how multicast DNS works, including how to name local services (e.g., myapplication.local).  You can't use single-label names in general for DNS names, that triggers use of other flat naming systems in browser/apps (e.g., host table and WINS).

Comment: I tried to run Wireshark listening on 5353 UDP, then I opened a webbrowser and I asked for http://test.local and wireshark did not get anything from that query. Why? I'm sure Wireshark is listening for MDNS packets because I could get other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support multicast dns.
Windows 10 only supports it to discover printers.
It does however support netbios name services and Link Local Multicast Name Resolution.
LLMNR is an RFC, and supported by linux.
Personally I am going to try out netbios and LLMNR, as the amount of windows 10 is less than 1%, and even then it is partially supported.